# How does stereo audio signal works with shared ground (e.g. headphone cables)

Tags: audio, ac

I have a rather simple question about my fundamental lack of knowledge how is stereo signal transferred along 3 wire cable (L,R channels and ground)?

The problem with me understanding it is because as I understand the signal is AC voltage for both channels, right, but how are they then sharing the same ground? Wouldn't that produce crosstalk for L and R channels because they both use ground to carry the negative part of their AC signal?

What am I fundamentally misunderstanding?

Comment: you can avoid crosstalk with coating, galvanik decoupling and so on.
I am not too sure how the circuit is build, but i imagine that this methods are used to prevent the signals from interfering themselves.

Comment: How would a phone like any Android/iPhone output signal if you know?

Comment: @StjepanV: Please do not try to hijack someone else's question.

Comment: I'm still not getting it unfortunately... My understanding of AC is basically that two signal paths alternate with polarity, right? So you would have for example 1st path having + polarity (conducting "forward") and 2nd path having the - polarity, and then they could switch. When we have two AC signals going through the same wire, wouldn't that cause adding or subtraction of voltage levels and fundamentally change the signal?

Comment: @Transistor Ha?

Comment: @StjepanV: Sorry, the question appeared unrelated to the original post. I didn't notice that it was the OP.

Comment: @StjepanV AC is not "two signal paths alternating with polarity."  AC is transmitted across two wires where the *relationship* between the voltage of the wires alternates between positive and negative polarity.  Each wire, on its own, doesn't really have a polarity.  It's the relationships between them that matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The left channel is a loop on it's own connecting the left AC voltage to the Left (headphone) speaker.

Same for the Right channel, it is also an **independent loop**.

Now "by coincidence" the ground of both loops are connected. That does not change anything for the loops themselves as the current/signal flowing inside the loop cannot "escape", it stays in the loop.

The Left loop has its own signal and so does the Right loop. As long as there is only **ONE** connection between the loops, this works.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRJZGn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 17):

There is slight crosstalk introduced. However, this is usually little enough to be negligible in actual consumer use.

If the ground wire were an 'ideal ground', that is absolutely zero resistance and inductance, there would be no crosstalk. That's because although the ground wire carries the current for both channels, because it's a perfect ground it always has zero volts at each end, so each of the left and right channel can reference an ideal 0 volt ground.

In practice, the ground wire has some resistance, let's say it has 0.1 ohms. If that cable is feeding a pair of 32 ohm headphones, that ratio is 320:1, or roughly 50dB, approximately the level of the crosstalk that would be generated. That is a better channel separation than vinyl records or multiplexed FM ever achieve, and once you put two loudspeakers in the same room, is anybody really worried about better than even 10dB?

If that cable were feeding another amplifier, rather than headphones, the input impedance would be much higher than 32ohms, and the ratio better, that is, practically perfect.

In studio work, all signals are carried individually.

Comment: I think that's what my second paragraph says, I even explain why, but I haven't bolded it up.

Comment: It does, my bad.

Comment: `In studio work, all signals are carried individually.` -- even better... balanced.

Comment: As a side note, in headphones/earbuds some crosstalk is desirable (at least IMO), because most mixes are made for speakers. The air between the speaker and the listener's head introduces lots of crosstalk between the left and right channel. In headphones, this does not happen, leading to exaggerated stereo separation.

Comment: The numbers here are on the pessimistic end. A quick check with my headphones shows a cable resistance of no more than 0.01 ohms (ohm-meter shows 0, and claims to be able to show a resistance of 0.01 as non-zero) and a nominal impedance of 600 ohms. That works out to cross-talk being around 95-96 dB down (or better).

Comment: @Dampmaskin ground lead impedance *widens* the stereo separation, fortauntely by not too much.

Comment: @JerryCoffin 0.1ohms was optimistic, had you considered the variable impedance of a nasty 3.5 jack socketground connection? My headphones have conductors that look like tinsel+string. I think you'll find most headphones are 8 ohm (pro) or 32 ohm (consumer). 600 ohm is rarely found in audio, telephony yes.

Comment: 8 ohm "pro" headphones often have "pro" 1/4 inch (6.3mm) connectors and thicker cables to match, not the flimsy 3.5mm connectors and cables on consumer audio equipment. 600 ohms was a standard impedance for long audio cables (i.e. up to a few kilometers) - which is irrelevant now, since wireless communications are cheap. 600 ohm phones could be tapped directly into those cables, without the transformers that were needed for low impedance loudspeakers.

Comment: @Neil_UK: It is optimistic in one respect: I was measuring only the DC resistance, not the impedance of the wiring (but I'd guess it's pretty low-capacitance wire, so the impedance probably won't be too terrible). Doing a quick check, it appears that (for one example) all the high-end Sennheiser headphones (HD-580 up to the HD-800) are rated at 300 ohms impedance (so ~3 dB less than with 600 ohms).

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBkl9n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Stereo headphone wiring. The common return from the speakers is connected to the jack sleeve which will connect to GND when plugged in.*

There isn't really a problem. As long as the return conductor resistance is low relative to the resistance / impedance of the speakers then the speakers lower terminals will be held at GND.